# Real time audio streaming with nodejs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying as :

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, function (stream) {
```

using socket.io-stream

```
ss(socket).emit('audio-stream', data, { name: filename });
```

But didn't know is this  the right library or way to implement real time audio chat. I am new to this, so not sure.

I google a lot and found :
WebRTC, PeerJs etc.

But I am looking to implement it in nodejs with socket.io.

Please suggest me right path and direction.

I am creating for Android and IOS app

Comment: I need to create audio chat same as skype

Answer (score 0):

[Hey try implementing it using this](https://github.com/nwah/peerjs-audio-chat)

```
// handle browser prefixes
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || 
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
navigator.msGetUserMedia);

// Get access to microphone
navigator.getUserMedia (
// Only request audio
{video: false, audio: true},

// Success callback
function success(localAudioStream) {
// Do something with audio stream
},
// Failure callback
function error(err) {
// handle error
}
);
```

Comment: I am just thinking, how to build, code is not complete. Need an idea how to build audio chat server, which can store audio and real time communication with group user.

Comment: I need to record and broadcast the stream in the room from the server .